# How to convert a triplet DataFrame to a new DataFrame with no duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames named df1 and df2, which are defined as follow:

```
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame( {
'id':       ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
'year':     [2015, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2017],
'amount':   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] } )

>> df2 = pd.DataFrame( {
    'id':   ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    '2015': [1, np.NaN, 6],
    '2016': [2, 4, np.NaN],
    '2017': [3, 5, 7] } )

>> df1
   amount id  year
0       1  A  2015
1       2  A  2016
2       3  A  2017
3       4  B  2016
4       5  B  2017
5       6  C  2015
6       7  C  2017

>> df2
   2015  2016  2017 id
0   1.0   2.0     3  A
1   NaN   4.0     5  B
2   6.0   NaN     7  C
```

As you can see, these two DataFrames contain the same information. DataFrame df1 is a triplet while df2 is a DataFrame with no duplicate values in its field id.

My question is how can I use pandas to convert df1 to df2 in a effective way ( without a for loop ) ?
And how about df2 to df1?

Comment: You just need `pivot`. `df1.pivot('id', 'year', 'amount')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot df1 to get df2 like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, index='id', columns='year', values = 'amount')


year    2015    2016    2017
id          
A       1       2       3
B       NaN     4       5
C       6       NaN     7
```

And melt to do the reverse

```
pd.melt(df2, id_vars=["id"],var_name="year", value_name="amount").dropna()


    id  year    amount
0   A   2015    1
2   C   2015    6
3   A   2016    2
4   B   2016    4
6   A   2017    3
7   B   2017    5
8   C   2017    7
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much!